# Unable to load saved career in Ashes Cricket 2017-18 PC

Tags: ashes-cricket-2017

One day as usual I loaded my last saved career, but it gave a message saying it could not load. After that the only option I have is to I can only create a new career, and I cannot load my previous career. I have the saved file of my career but it's not showing up inside the 'load career' option of the game. I took a backup of my existing career file and after that started a new career, saved it and replaced the new created files with my old files. Now, only the name of my previous career comes up, but when I click on it, it opens the career of the newly-created player. I want to get back my career in Ashes Cricket 17. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue with being unable to load my career :(